# Code under .Success in Angular controller doesn't run

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am having a problem that I don't understand and I need your help. I am using AngularJS with ASP.Net MVC. In my application, I have a list of users, when I select a user and click on save button, it assigns that user as a supervisor. However, let me show you my code first and then I will tell you about the problem:

View:

```
<div ng-show="!svElements" class="item_list">{{supervisor}}</div>
<div ng-show="svElements">
    <select id="svList" ng-model="svListModel">
         <option ng-repeat="x in supervisors" value="{{x.supervisorId}}">{{x.supervisorfName + " " + x.supervisorlName}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Angular Controller:

```
$scope.updateUserSupervisor = function () {
    $http.post('/Home/UpdateUserSupervisor', { svList: document.getElementById('svList').value })
        .success(function (result) {
            $scope.users = result;
            $scope.supervisor = result[0].sfName + " " + result[0].slName;
            $scope.svElements = !$scope.svElements;
        })
        .error(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
}
```

My problem is, I have a problem with my angular controller's code! Although the update is done correctly with the database using the $http.post, the code inside .success doesn't run?

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Comment: Does the code inside your `error` function run? By the way, `success` and `error` are deprecated and you should really be using `.then()`, `.catch()` and `.finally()`. Also, why are you using `document.getElementById('svList').value` instead of `$scope.svListModel`? You've set up two-way databinding with `ng-model` and then you're not using it.

Comment: Thank you very much, would you please give me an example? I am new to this.